# Forcing a discriminated union match

Tags: typescript

**Scenario**

I'm a typescript beginner trying to port the `mapProps` function below to typescript

```
const addOne = x => x + 1
const upperCase = x => x.toUpperCase()

const obj = {
  entry: 'legend',
  fauna: {
    unicorns: 10,
    zombies: 3
  },
  other: {
    hat: 2
  }
}

const fns = {
  entry: upperCase,
  fauna: {
    unicorns: addOne
  },
  other: obj => ({
      hat: addOne(obj.hat)
  })
}

const mapProps = (obj, fns) => 
    Object.keys(fns).reduce(
        (acc, cur) => ({
            ...acc,
            [cur]: fns[cur] instanceof Function
                ? fns[cur](obj[cur])
                : mapProps(obj[cur], fns[cur])
        }),
        obj
    )

mapProps(obj, fns) 
// ​​​​​{ entry: 'LEGEND',​​​​​ fauna: { unicorns: 11, zombies: 3 },​​​​​ other: { hat: 3 } }​​​​​
```

**Current attempt**

```
type MapPropFuncsOf<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ((x:T[P]) => T[P]) | MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>
}

const mapProps = <T>(obj:T, fns: MapPropFuncsOf<T>) => 
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
        (acc, cur) => ({
            ...acc,
            [cur]: fns[cur] instanceof Function
                ? fns[cur]!(obj[cur]) // compiler warning
                : mapProps(obj[cur], fns[cur]) // compiler warning
        }),
        obj
  )
```

**Issues**

Even though I have checked that `fns[cur] instanceof Function` I can't seem to call `fns[cur]`, the typescript compiler complains with

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   'MapPropFuncsOf | ((x: T[keyof T]) => T[keyof T])' has no
>   compatible call signatures.

The `mapProps(obj[cur], fns[cur])` call also fails with

> Argument of type 'MapPropFuncsOf | ((x: T[keyof T]) =>
>   T[keyof T]) | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'MapPropFuncsOf'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to
>   type 'MapPropFuncsOf'.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20addOne%20%3D%20(x%3Anumber)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%0D%0Aconst%20upperCase%20%3D%20(x%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20x.toUpperCase()%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20entry%3A%20'legend'%2C%0D%0A%20%20fauna%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unicorns%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20zombies%3A%203%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20other%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hat%3A%202%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fns%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20entry%3A%20upperCase%2C%0D%0A%20%20fauna%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20unicorns%3A%20addOne%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20other%3A%20(obj%3Aany)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hat%3A%20addOne(obj.hat)%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0AWorking%20js%20implementation%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mapProps%20%3D%20(obj%2C%20fns)%20%3D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.keys(fns).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(acc%2C%20cur)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...acc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcur%5D%3A%20fns%5Bcur%5D%20instanceof%20Function%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20fns%5Bcur%5D(obj%5Bcur%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20mapProps(obj%5Bcur%5D%2C%20fns%5Bcur%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MapPropFuncsOf%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20((x%3AT%5BP%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%5BP%5D)%20%7C%20MapPropFuncsOf%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mapProps%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(obj%3AT%2C%20fns%3A%20MapPropFuncsOf%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(Object.keys(fns)%20as%20(keyof%20T)%5B%5D).reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(acc%2C%20cur)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...acc%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bcur%5D%3A%20fns%5Bcur%5D%20instanceof%20Function%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20fns%5Bcur%5D!(obj%5Bcur%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20mapProps(obj%5Bcur%5D%2C%20fns%5Bcur%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%0D%0A%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0AmapProps(obj%2C%20fns))

Comment: I think we are going to have to use type assertions here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a typescript newbie.. is that like a dynamic cast?

Comment: It's not a cast, a cast usually has runtime behavior associated with it. This is just telling the compiler ignore what you think know, I know better.  I can add the type assertion based solution.

Comment: Is there perhaps a better way to right this method? Seems like a lot of typescript for what amounts to a single line javascript implementation

Comment: How would you write it in JS in one line ? With assertions to `any` (`x as any`) you can write anything in TS :)

Comment: Does it work if you replace the `instanceof` with `typeof fns[cur] === 'function'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is caused by the fact that typescript will not narrow index expressions that contain dynamic values. The simple solution is to put the value in a variable

```
declare var o: { [s: string]: string | number }
declare var n: string
if(typeof o[n] === "string") { o[n].toLowerCase(); } //error

let v = o[n]
if(typeof v === "string") { v.toLowerCase(); } // ok
```

So this code will not throw an error on calling the function:

```
const mapProps = <T>(obj:T, fns: MapPropFuncsOf<T>): T => 
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
        (acc, cur) =>
        {
          var fn = fns[cur];
          return ({
            ...acc,
            [cur]: typeof fn === "function"
                ? fn(obj[cur], null) 
                : mapProps(obj[cur], fns[cur]) 
        })
      },
        obj
  )
```

The above is still not perfect. `fn` is called with two arguments which is not expected. This is actually due to an inconsistency in your code. After all there is nothing stopping `T` from having function properties. With your signature you end up calling functions that might not expect.

We can constrain `T` to not contain any functions:

```
type MapPropFuncsOf<T extends Values> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ((x:T[P]) => T[P]) | (T[P] extends Values ? MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>: T[P])
}

interface Values {
  [s: string] : string | number | boolean | null | undefined | Values
}

const mapProps = <T extends Values>(obj:T, fns: MapPropFuncsOf<T>) => 
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
        (acc, cur) =>
        {
          var fn = fns[cur];
          return ({
            ...acc,
            [cur]: typeof fn === "function"
                ? fn(obj[cur])  // fully checked now
                : mapProps(obj[cur], fns[cur]) 
        })
      },
        obj
  )
```

The issue around calling `mapProps` stem from similar issues, but are not easily fixable.
Since we added the `T extends Values` constraint we can only call `mapProps` with something that satisfies that constraint.  We can put `obj[cur]` in a variable lets say `o`, but that will not help us narrow the value to `Values` with a `typeof o == "object"` type-guard. We can us a type assertion or a custom type guard to get out of this last issue.

Also there is probably no point in calling `mapProps` recursively for primitive types, so I will use a custom type guard that just checks for `object`.

```
type MapPropFuncsOf<T extends Values> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ((x:T[P]) => T[P]) | (T[P] extends Values ? MapPropFuncsOf<T[P]>: T[P])
}

interface Values {
  [s: string] : string | number | boolean |  Values
}
function isValues(o: Values[string]) : o is Values {
  return typeof o === "object"
}
const mapProps = <T extends Values>(obj:T, fns: MapPropFuncsOf<T>) : T=> 
    (Object.keys(fns) as (keyof T)[]).reduce(
        (acc, cur) =>
        {
          var fn = fns[cur];
          var o = obj[cur];
          return ({
            ...acc,
            [cur]: typeof fn === "function"
                ? fn(obj[cur]) 
                : (isValues(o) ? mapProps(o, fn as any) : o)
        })
      },
        obj
  )
```

The last point would be that `fn` is not checkable to be a valid `MapPropFuncsOf` for `o`, so I used `fn as any` I'm afraid this is where the bag of tricks ran out.

**Note**

While it is interesting to try to write a fully typed version of your function,  there are limit to what the typescript type system can model. Especially with generic functions, it is more important for the client code to be fully type checked, which it is. If in the implementation we need to break out of the type-safety sandbox a bit it might not be a horrible thing as long as we are explicit about it and have a good reason to do so. A type assertion version is already in another answer so I'm not going to duplicate it here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning. Your modifiers are missing types. Let's add them.

```
const addOne = (x: number) => x + 1;
const upperCase = (x: string) => x.toUpperCase();
```

Both functions conform to the signature of an *identity function* — they accept an argument of some type and return exactly the same type.

```
type Identity<T> = (argument: T) => T;
```

Your `fns` are a collection of such functions. Once we're done, the type of `obj` will remain unaffected. However, it's not that simple — sometimes the identity function applies to the primitive value, sometimes to a subtree of your object. If we were to model the relationship between `obj` and `fns`, it would be something like that:

```
type DeepIdentity<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object
    ? DeepIdentity<T[K]> | Identity<T[K]>
    : Identity<T[K]>
}
```

Let's see if our definition is correct.

```
const fns: DeepIdentity<typeof obj> = {
  entry: upperCase,
  fauna: {
    unicorns: addOne,
  },
  other: obj => ({
      hat: addOne(obj.hat)
  })
}
```

With that in place, your processing function could be defined as:

```
const process = <T>(input: T, transformers: DeepIdentity<T>): T =>
  (Object.keys(input) as (keyof T)[])
    .reduce(
      (accumulator, property) => {
        const transformer = transformers[property];
        const value = input[property];

        return Object.assign(accumulator, {
          [property]: (transformer === undefined)
            ? value
            : (transformer instanceof Function)
              ? transformer(value)
              : process(value, transformer as DeepIdentity<typeof value>)
        });
      },
      {} as T
    )

process(obj, fns); // { "entry": "LEGEND", "fauna": { "unicorns": 11, "zombies": 3 }, "other": { "hat": 3 } }
```